# How Can I filter and remove title Categories from array of array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list separated by alphabetical categories. All that start with the letter `A` are grouped, letter `B` are grouped and so on.

When I filter this list, the titles corresponding to each letter do not disappear. The filter is working, but the screen is loaded with the titles of the letters.

When I make the filter, can you tell me how I can remove a letter category that is not being used?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-cherry-ifjq8f?file=/src/index.js)

Thank you for any help.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { data } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");

  const _data = Object.values(
    data.reduce((c, e) => {
      if (!c[e.id]) {
        c[e.id] = e;
      }

      return c;
    }, {})
  );

  const merged = [];
  _data.map((arr) => arr.map((item) => merged.push(item)));

  const mapped = merged.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const letter = item.title[0].toLowerCase();
    if (!acc[letter]) {
      acc[letter] = [];
    }
    acc[letter].push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const letters = Object.keys(mapped);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Grouped by the first initial</h1>
      <div>
        <input value={filter} onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      {letters.map((letter, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <h2>{letter}</h2>
          {mapped[letter]
            .filter(
              (inputFilter) =>
                inputFilter.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >=
                0
            )
            .map((item, j) => (
              <div key={j}>{item.title}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could show letter if and even if filter search got result:

So letter visibility becomes:

```
 {letterIsVisible(letter) && <h2>{letter}</h2>}
```

where `letterIsVisible` is a function like:

```
const letterIsVisible = (letter) => {
    return (
      mapped[letter].filter(
        (inputFilter) =>
          inputFilter.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0
      ).length > 0
    );
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-frost-qmceq5?file=/src/App.js) your codesandbox modified.